# Javascript - Find seconds between two MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss formatted dates?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to use two MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss formatted dates to find the time in seconds between them. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Date.parse(...)` to parse the dates to create a `Date` object.

With `.valueOf()` on the created object you get the epoch (milliseconds since January 1st 1970) of this date.

Do this with both dates and substract the numbers. The difference is the time in milliseconds between the dates. The rest should be clear :)

**Edit:**

Following discussion in comments, here is the more valid reference to `Date` object: 
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor

Comment: No, absolutely do not do that. Date strings should always be manually parsed (a library can help). The authoritative reference for the Date object is the language specification ([*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor)), MDN is a public wiki that is not a standard or specification, though it is a handy reference.

Comment: So what is the difference between using a (third-party) library for doing a simple thing and using the Date object which is supported by all browsers out of the box? 1. As you have pointed out it is completely following ECMAScript standards even though I cited MDN (it is completely irrelevant to the question). 2. I suggest manual parsing by using Date.parse(), which is completely valid if you have ISO 8601 formatted dates.

Comment: + Time difference will always be the same no matter if the date produced is UTC or local.

Comment: The difference is that the language specification says implementations can treat the format in the OP any way they like, including not parsing it at all. So **any** result you get is per the specification. The format in the OP is not an ISO 8601 format, ECMA-262 only specifies a [*subset of the ISO 8601 formats*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) and not all browsers in use are ES5 compliant in regard to Date objects.

Comment: That I didn't realise until now. It always worked for me in that way, even with different browsers. I had exactly the same time format coming from the backend. However I understand now that one should be agnostic and not rely on possible side effects from different clients.

Answer (score 0):

You should never parse date string using the Date constructor or Date.parse (which do the same thing), always manually parse the string. A library can help, but for specific formats, a parse function is pretty simple.

The format MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss is not one that is specified as supported by ES5 or later, so it will fall back to implementation dependent heuristics. Some browsers may parse it as local or UTC, and some may allow out of range values and others not. Some may not parse it at all.

A simple parse function (that doesn't validate values) is below.

Adding validation requires a little more code, but if you are confident that the provided data is good then it's not required.

To find the difference in seconds between two dates, simply subtract one from the other (which gives the difference in milliseconds) and divide by 1,000.

```js
function parseMDYhms(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[0]-1, b[1], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
}

var d0 = parseMDYhms('01-18-2015 12:52:13');
var d1 = parseMDYhms('01-19-2015 15:23:21');

var diffSeconds = (d1 - d0) / 1000;

document.write('Difference: ' + diffSeconds + ' seconds');
```